# Need to require only one of a group of fields with Parsley

Tags: parsley.js

I am using `Parsley.js` for validating a form submission on a project. One of my needs is to have Parsley require that at least one of three fields have data in them, and only fail validation if none of the three fields has data.

I am not sure from the documentation, how to accomplish this. I already have Parsley validation working on the rest of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a custom validator like so

```
var CheckReccursion = 0;
    window.Parsley.addValidator('min3', {
        validateString: function (value, requirement, instance) {
            var notice =$('#notice').html(' ');

            var group = $(requirement);//a class

            var FieldsEmpty = 0;
            var FieldsNotEmpty = 0;
            var count = 0

            group.each(function () {

                var _val = $(this).val()
                var length = _val.length

                if (length > 0) {
                    FieldsNotEmpty++;
                }
                else {
                    FieldsEmpty++;
                }
                count++;
            })

            var isValid = (FieldsNotEmpty >=1)
            //recursively execute
            group.each(function (index) {
                if (CheckReccursion === index) {
                    CheckReccursion++;
                    $(this).parsley().validate();
                    CheckReccursion = 0;
                }
            })
            return isValid;
        }
    });

$(function () {
    var ok=false;
    var notice =$('#notice');

    $('#form1').parsley().on('form:validated', function(formInstance) {
        ok = formInstance.isValid({force: true});
    })
    .on('form:submit', function() {
        if(!ok){
            notice.html('Please fill at least 1 field');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            notice.html('okay');
            return false;//change to true to submit form here

        }
    });
});
```

then add parsley attributes to the group of fields like so:

```
<form id="form1" data-parsley-validate="true">
    <input type="text" name="field1"

    data-parsley-min3 = ".group1"
    data-parsley-min3-message = "At least 1 must be filled"
    class="group1">



    <input type="text" name="field2"

    data-parsley-min3 = ".group1"
    data-parsley-min3-message = "At least 1 must be filled"
    class="group1">

    <input type="text" name="field3"

    data-parsley-min3 = ".group1"
    data-parsley-min3-message = "At least 1 must be filled"
    class="group1">



    <span id="notice"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xcoL5Lur/6/

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to add hidden checkbox element with the attribute:

> data-parsley-mincheck="1"

now just add javascript code that checks the hidden checkbox attribute when your form input has value (and the opposite).

notice that you will need to add extra attribute to your hidden checkbox:

> data-parsley-error-message="Please fill at least one input"

Comment: The current documentation referencing `mincheck` as valid for #2.0.

Comment: valid for what ?

Comment: It says: `Validates that a certain maximum number of checkboxes in a group are checked.`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to using `data-parsley-group` and the `isValid({group,force})` method.

```
<input type="text" name="input1" data-parsley-group="group1">
<input type="text" name="input2" data-parsley-group="group2">
<input type="text" name="input3" data-parsley-group="group3">

$('#myform').parsley().on('form:validate', function (formInstance) {
    if(formInstance.isValid({group: 'group1', force: true}) || 
       formInstance.isValid({group: 'group2', force: true}) ||
       formInstance.isValid({group: 'group3', force: true})) {
       //do nothing
    }
    else {        
        $('#errorContainer').html('You must correctly fill at least one of these three groups!');
        formInstance.validationResult = false;
    }
});
```

1. you can add as many as parsley's attributes as you wish, like `data-parsley-type="email"` that will be validated when the given input is not empty.
2. we set the `force: true` because it it forces validation even on non-required.fields.
3. the html render for the errorContainer is needed because the isValid method does not affect UI nor fires events.